# mcrypt_encrypt & mcrypt_decrypt doesn't work on localhost

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I use mcrypt_decrypt and encrypt to my live website. Now, I would like to change some codes on it and test it on localhost. The encrypting/decrypting works well on my live web, but not on localhost. I echo each encryted variable to see if there are value but it seems no work at all. Any idea?

```
$secret_key ="qazxsw";
$email="myemail1@email.com"; 

$encrypted_data = trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $email, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));


echo $encrypted_data ;
```

EDIT: XAMPP-5.6.3[image]

Comment: Don't use that code. It's insecure.

Comment: do you have any suggestion? @Scott Arciszewski

Comment: Yes: If you're storing passwords, use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. Otherwise, use https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption which gives you authenticated encryption (i.e. it is *actually secure*).

Comment: @ScottArciszewski.What i want to encrypt and decrypt is email address, I have used different types of encryption and decryption methods. But it decrypts the encrypted data with different output. This code helps me with decryption method same with the original email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have take this error beacuse this Algorythm you used is not suppor 8 char keys,

please increase your `$secretkey=""` to 16 char below codes

```
<?PHP
$secret_key ="qazxswqazxswqazx";
$email="myemail1@email.com"; 

$encrypted_data = trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $email, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));


echo $encrypted_data ;
?>
```

OutPut :

```
F2GUGzXHKXZruXDpAwMWBeSzwcRKS+CYl/ekUt+dHto=
```

Comment: It seems that the plugin is not installed to my computer. Can you guide me on how to install it. I'm using window 7 O.S.

Comment: xkevin which server you use on lacal. xammp wamp or etc ?

Comment: My server on local is xampp.

Comment: did you check with phpinfo(); function installed ?

Comment: I attached an image.

Comment: did you take an error report ? it take please add the question we must see error report

Comment: The following warnings occurred:
Warning [2] mcrypt_encrypt(): Encryption mode requires an initialization vector of size 8 - Line: 322 @Ivan Barayev

Comment: I update my answer please try it I tried and worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
function encryptIt( $value ) {
        $cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5U453G03efyCp';

        $qEncoded  = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), $value, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
        return( $qEncoded );
    }
```